# Simple Sturm-Liouville Problem $(Lx)(t)=-x''(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the SL operator $L=-\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ and the boundary conditions

$f'(0)=0,\ f'(1)+f(1)=0$

I want to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Since we have $f''+zf=0$ the solution is given by

$f=c_1\sin(\sqrt{z}x)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{z}x)$

The first boundary condition $f'(0)=0$ gives $c_1=0$ and the second one

$c_2\left ( \cos(\sqrt{z})-\sin(\sqrt{z})\sqrt{z}\right )=0$ so we need

$z=\mathrm{cotan}^2(\sqrt{z})$

I am not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all that there is to this problem. Perhaps you should add some remark why you exclude negative $z$ resp. how they are still included in the formula.

Then you can try to find quantitative properties of the eigenvalues, for large $z$ these will be close to the poles $\sqrt{z}\approx k\pi$ of the co-tangent. Then with $\sqrt{z}=k\pi+u_1$
$$
(k\pi+u_1)=\cot(k\pi+u_1)=\cot(u_1)
$$
has the approximate solution
$$
u_1\approx\tan(u_1)=\frac1{k\pi+u_1}\approx\frac1{k\pi}-\frac{u_1}{k^2\pi^2}
$$
so that
$$
u_1\approx\frac{k\pi}{1+k^2\pi^2}.
$$

Numerical computation confirms that formula

```
 k     x0=k*pi       x1=x0+x0/(1+x0^2)   numerical sol.

 1   3.14159265359     3.43061813581     3.42561845948
 2   6.28318530718     6.43840840331     6.43729817917
 3   9.42477796077     9.52970005277     9.52933440536
 4  12.5663706144     12.6454473268     12.6452872239
 5  15.7079632679     15.7713682744     15.7712848748
 6  18.8495559215     18.9024586756     18.9024099569
 7  21.9911485751     22.0365275822     22.0364967279
 8  25.1327412287     25.1724670728     25.1724463266
 9  28.2743338823     28.3096574619     28.3096428545
10  31.4159265359     31.4477253056     31.4477146375
11  34.5575191895     34.5864322411     34.5864242153
12  37.6991118431     37.725619016      37.7256128278
13  40.8407044967     40.8651752015     40.8651703305
14  43.9822971503     44.0050218233     44.0050179208
15  47.1238898038     47.1451009112     47.1450977368
16  50.2654824574     50.2853689545     50.2853663378
17  53.407075111      53.4257926597     53.4257904774
18  56.5486677646     56.5663461188     56.5663442798
19  59.6902604182     59.7070088694     59.7070073053
20  62.8318530718     62.8477645357     62.8477631945
21  65.9734457254     65.9885998573     65.9885986985
22  69.115038379      69.1295039819     69.1295029739
23  72.2566310326     72.2704679426     72.2704670603
24  75.3982236862     75.4114842655     75.4114834888
```

Comment: For the positivity of the operator I showed that $\langle Lx,x\rangle \ge 0$ by integrating by parts.